# Dual management node for mysql clustering

Tags: mysql, clustering, ndbcluster, failover

I currently have mysql cluster setup and running. 
Here is my current setup:
1 - management node
2 - data nodes
2 - mysql nodes

I wish to incorporate a failover for the management node. The management node seems to be the bottleneck in my current setup. If the management node fails, my entire cluster is down. How can I incorporate a dual management node settings? Is it possible to have a 2nd management node? Must I also increase my data node and mysql node to accommodate the 2nd management node. Please assist.

This is what I have in my config.ini now: The 2 data nodes is together with my management node. I have separate out the mysql nodes.

```
[ndb_mgmd]
hostname=192.168.0.1
datadir=c:\Users\user1\my_cluster\ndb_data
NodeId=1
[ndbd default]
noofreplicas=2
datadir=c:\Users\user1\my_cluster\ndb_data
[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.0.1
NodeId=3
[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.0.1
NodeId=4
[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.0.2
NodeId=5
[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.0.3
nodeId=6
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the two data nodes on one server means that if you lose 192.168.0.1 (node 3/node 4) you lose the whole cluster (possibly why you are experiencing the failure).

In fact the fact that you have effectively a single data node (unless I'm missing something) means you don't really have a cluster - you only have one copy of data.

Comment: btw just to add - losing the mgmt node shouldn't effect the availability of the cluster. the mgmt node is to start the cluster but the mysqld and ndbd nodes determine the availability of the cluster response and cluster data.

Comment: but when I lose the management node, my entire cluster is not connected. Why is that? How do you test if the management node is down, the cluster is still working?

Comment: Since you have 2 data nodes in your MySQL Cluster setup both on same server(ip), and managment node also resides on same machine , it shouldn't happen that if managment node is down the cluster should be running also make sure that you are initiating both data nodes , because until you don't start both data nodes the cluster will not start.